# Display reoccurring events within date range

Tags: postgresql

I am putting together a small call planner.
Calls are created and can be a once off event, or every week, month or yearly events beginning at a given time.

I can use generate_series to produce a list of dates, and this can JOIN the call_schedule table, but it is only including them for the date they begin.

I need the dates to show a list of dates selected with generate_series.
Eg: if it was every Monday at 9:30am there would be an entry for every Monday at 09:30:00 in the list of dates.
Dates without any calls would simply be empty, showing only the dates.

I have made a few attempts, and have put together sample data.
Any progress on this greatly appreciated.
http://derp.co.uk/559b1

Thanks
Kev

Comment: use https://github.com/petropavel13/pg_rrule

Comment: Thanks Neil, but can this not be done with generate_series? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kevin: Neil's reference towards pg_rrule is a simplification of what generate_series does, with the boiler plate code taken out for simplification / maintenance. You may chose to duplicate that effort in your SQL, both are valid, just one simpler than the other.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I cant even get it to compile. Also, this may not be a good solution for portability.